# Question About Pointwise Multiplication Of Complex Numbers

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $P[z_0,\dots,z_{n-1}]$ be a formal polynomial over $\bf C$ using some multiplication $*:\bf C\to C$ to be specified later on.  So e.g. $P[z_0,z_1]=1+1*z_0+i*z_0*z_1+(-1)*z_1$

I wonder if for every $P$ and $\phi\in S^1$ there exists $P'$ such that $\phi P[z_0,\dots,z_{n-1}]=P'[\phi z_0,\dots,\phi z_{n-1}]$?

If it makes things easier, I'm actually just interested in $$\frac{\phi(P[z_0,\dots,z_{n-1}])}{\|\phi(P[z_0,\dots,z_{n-1}])\|}=\frac{P'[\phi z_0,\dots,\phi z_{n-1}]}{\|P'[\phi z_0,\dots,\phi z_{n-1}]\|}$$ whenever the former is defined.

For $*$ being the standard complex multiplication, this seems clear to me, but what about pointwise multiplication, i.e. $(a+bi)*(c+di)=(ac+bdi)$?

I think it might boil down to the case $n=2$ and $P[z_0,z_1]=z_0*z_1$.

[EDIT] Simplified the question.  Also, pretty sure the answer is no as there seems to be no rewriting of $\sin(x+t)\sin(y+t)$ (or alternatively $\cos(x+t)\cos(y+t)$) as sum of real polynomials $P[\sin(x),\sin(y)]+Q[\cos(x),\cos(y)]$, does that make any sense?

Comment: what is the pointwise complex multiplication?

Comment: Just pointwise multiplication on ${\bf R}^2$, so $(a,b)*(c,b)=(ac,bd)$.

Comment: In the multiplications $\phi P$ and $\phi_iz$ are you using the standard product of complex numbers or the same $*$?

Comment: Here I use the standard product, so $\phi$ just rotates the value.

Comment: Notice that $|\phi z|=|\phi| \cdot |z|$, but it doesn't hold with pointwise multiplication